# Need an input device between tablet and smartpen

Tags: drawing-tablet, sketching

This question is a bit complicated to sum up in the title. I know there are a few technologies when it comes to digitizing your drawings.

1. Tablets like Intuos and Bamboo
2. Smartpens like Livescribe Echo

My gripe with graphics tablets is the hand eye coordination because I want to look where I am drawing. On the other hand with Livescribe smartpens, I can look where I am writing but it only records the movements and does not let you control the mouse cursor in realtime on a computer. What I really want is something in between; to be able to handwrite with a pen on a regular paper and simultaneously control the mouse cursor on the monitor.

I hope I explained it sufficiently well. I need such an input device for the purpose of making instructional videos such that the videos contain my writings and doodles as I speak. Please point to an appropriate solution.

Comment: Wacom used to have real writing pens for its ancient UX series of tablets. Wonder if they still make any.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for the [Wacom Inkling](http://www.wacom.com/en/Products/Inkling.aspx), [Wacom Cintiq](http://www.wacom.com/en/Products/Cintiq.aspx), or related product. I don't have any experience with these directly, but I believe they will work.

Comment: I have been on the lookout of Inkling but they have delayed it multiple times. God knows when it is going to come out! That's why I didn't mention it in the question, but I think it will work for my purpose. Cintiq is simply way out of my budget. I am a student :)

Comment: @Aamir: If that is the case, put that kind of detail into your question. If budget is a consideration, we need to know if we can properly help you.

Comment: Inkling is neat, but doesn't address the OP's quest for something that will also control the cursor on the computer screen. Inkling is really an off-line digitizer, not a replacement for a mouse or tablet for actual interacting with the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Pearsonartphoto is probably right about needing a Cintiq.  The pens mostly just record for later import into your actual digital drawing app.

[I use a Cintiq](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/what-kind-of-tablet-are-pros-using/3188#3188) and it's not perfect, but it's probably as good as you're going to get for looking at your screen while drawing directly on it.

Comment: Echoing what Farray says, I know of better than a Cintiq. If you look at some of Bert Monroy's wonderful ["Pixel Perfect" tutorials on Revision3.com](http://revision3.com/search/search?q=pixel%20perfect&Submit.x=50&Submit.y=4), you'll see exactly how effective a Cintiq (or, in Bert's case, *two* Cintiqs) can be for this kind of application. There's even a series of "behind the scenes" videos on how the Pixel Perfect show was made.