# What size Wacom Intuos tablet should I get for drawing?

Tags: drawing-tablet

I'm a high school student, looking for a starter tablet since drawing is just a hobby for me currently. I've looked at multiple forums and discussions already but can't find the information I'm looking for. My question is which tablet size should I get: small or medium. I was going to get the small but then I saw some articles saying not too. My computer that I will probably be using is 17inches across, and almost 20inches diagonal. My hands are average to small size, and I'm used to drawing on A4 paper, but my drawings rarely take up more than 2/4th of the page.
Any help would be great! Thank you :)

Comment: Some answers [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27699/how-can-i-decide-between-the-medium-sized-intuos-tablet-or-the-small-one) might help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I decide between the medium sized intuos tablet or the small one?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27699/how-can-i-decide-between-the-medium-sized-intuos-tablet-or-the-small-one)

Answer (score 1):

This is an opinion based answer.

As you describe your drawing size paper, I think you draw with your wrist, but in time you could try drawing with your arm (to have more fluent strokes), so a bigger sensitive area can be usefull, read the specifications of the model you are looking but consider the "Active area".

Some people say that the screen size should be similar than the active area of the pen, but I don't think that is an issue. Bigger active area also means that you hand will work a little harder. But you can reduce the active areas on the configuration panel.

So, if you are not limited by phisical space or budget, a bigger active area is better for free hand drawing or painting.